# Taking random number as input in java from user

Tags: java, random

`

> ```
>   System.err.println("welcome to the game");
>         System.err.println("please throw your dice 10 times");
>         Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
>         Random r=new Random();
>         for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
>                 {
>                     System.err.println("try"+i);
>                   int d=  r.nextInt(6)+1;
>                     System.err.println(r.nextInt(10)+1);
>
>                 }
>
>          }
> ```

I have a question,I am developing a basic game dice rolling .I am a bit confused that how to take random number when user press enter key each time ,a new random number is generated ?here ,all the random no. is genereted at once.but I want it just like user inputs  any integer no or double etc  after pressing the enter key.

Comment: Where are you stuck with the code?

Comment: You take a _random_ number from the user?

Comment: actually I cant understand how to implement it.just i have to take random no. like  person throwing a dice,each time when he press enter key.

Comment: You never actually use the scanner in your code. Add an s.next(); in your for loop.

Comment: yes I know I have no idea that how to impement it to take random no. after hitting enter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you mean you want the user to press a button, and a new number is randomly generated.

First off, in Java, a random number is generated from the Random class.

You can import Random by saying, at the top of your code:

```
import java.util.*;
```

or, to be more precise:

```
import java.util.Random;
```

When you want to generate a random number in your main method, you must make a Random object, then create an instance of Random, since Java is an Object-Oriented Language. In other words, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random();
    int rantInt = r.nextInt(7); //random integer between 0 and 6
}
```

You could use the Scanner class to get user input; however, at your level, I would suggest simply rerunning the program to get a new random dice roll.

Also, on StackOverflow, as well as any other Stack Exchange website (or any forum, to be honest), you should be clear about your question. At the very least, write in complete sentences and with proper grammar. If possible, provide some of your source code, as well as your environment/experience.

Comment: And please use the search function: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+read+user+input